Better Pattern designto manage state in React JS
I'm developing a huge project for manage website with blocks.
So i have a ParentComponent that manage all the field of the form that are composed with some nested Components.
<FatherFormComponent>
const [test, setTest] = useState(true)
  <Field1 test={test}>
    <Component1 test={test}>
       <Component2 test={test}>
          {test}
       </Component2>
     </Component1>
  </Field1>
</FatherFormComponent>

Now i want to manage all the props of the father component with a state manager like zustand so i can call the variable or the function i need only in the component i prefer.
function Component2() {
const [test] = useStore(state=> [state.test])

return {test}
}

In this way i avoid to pass throght a lot of children component a props.
But i don't know if the performance of the components rendering is impacted.
Which is the best method for you in this case ?
